# PostgresSQL Using cursor to iterate through each record and set an incremental serial number if Id is the same

Tags: postgresql, loops, cursor

I'm new to PostgresSQL and trying to do something a beyond my current skillset.

I'm using cursor to iterate through each row and set an incremental serial number if the Id is the same.

1. My query doesn't seem to fetch records, I'm testing by trying to set serialNumber to 1 and it's not working.
2. I'm not sure how to write increment by one if the Id is the same, otherwise reset serialNumber back to 1.

Please help!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setSerial()
RETURNS int
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE 
    row_item record;
    
    cursorSub cursor for
        SELECT  "Id" AS uid, 
                "SerialNumber" AS SerialNumber
        FROM public."Drivers"
        GROUP BY "Id";

    BEGIN
        OPEN cursorSub;
        
            LOOP
                -- fetch the rows
                FETCH cursorSub INTO row_item;

                -- exit if no more rows
                EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

                -- build the output
                UPDATE public."Drivers"
                SET "SerialNumber" = 1 -- how to increment by one if Id is the name
                WHERE "id" = row_item.uid AND row_item.SerialNumber IS NULL;
            END LOOP;
        CLOSE cursorSub;
    END;
$$;
```

Here's a sample of the table:

| Id | ClientId | SubmissionId | Serial |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 5 | 2 |

Comment: Your SELECT statement from the cursor is invalid and won't even run.

Comment: You don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for this. This can be done with a single UPDATE statement that uses a window function to generate the serialnumber. But without more details it's really hard to write such an answer

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I ran the SELECT statement on it's own and it returns the expected table. Do I have to format it differently in a cursor? 
What other detail do you require from my question, other than the table is made of id(uuid), submissionid(uuid) and serial(int). the same ids can have different submissionid. Not sure if any of that helped.

Comment: Ah, right. If `Id` is the primary key, then this will work, but then the GROUP BY is totally useless. It would be much easier if you provided some sample data and the result based on that sample - as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name re. group makes sense! I've added a table in my response. Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: Note that the use of quoted identifiers is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) - they cause more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Comment: Thank you, not sure why pgAdmin 4 seems to force them or the query won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a window function to generate the `SerialNumber`

```
select "Id", "ClientId", "SubmissionId", 
       row_number() over (partition by "ClientId" order by "Id") as "SerialNumber"
from "Drivers"
```

This can be used as the source for an UPDATE statement:

```
update "Drivers"
   set "SerialNumber" = t.sn
from (
  select "Id", 
         row_number() over (partition by "ClientId" order by "Id") as sn       
  from "Drivers"
  where "SerialNumber" is null
) t
where t."Id" = "Drivers"."Id"
```